# Delete overlapping shapefile geometry by majority coverage?

Tags: postgresql, geometry, postgis, shapefile

I am trying to replace records in a table with new records containing updated geometry field values.

I have two tables that contain records with geometry fields. I would like to identify (& remove) all of the records in one table that are covered by a majority (>50%) by a geometry field in the other table. A lot of the fields overlap in minute ways so `ST_Intersects()` returns nearly all of the records. None of the records are completely contained by the records as well, so `ST_CoveredBy()` & `ST_Within()` return no records at all.

**How can I identify & remove all records with  geometry that the new geometry values overlap by a majority (>50%)?**

Comment: Do you mean A overlap B then remove B? Or A + C overlap B then remove B? And how you know what is the new geometry so delete the old ones?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza  In this case the individual records in A correspond to records in B so I don't need to account for multiple records covering a single record. if A overlaps B by more than 50% I want to remove B. I am then going to insert the records from A after all the overlapping records have been removed. This is a one-time update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function to use is ST_Intersection, which returns the geometry. You can then compare the area to the source area.
To make it more efficient, make sure that both geometry column are indexed and restrict the area computation to intersecting geometries only.

```
SELECT a.id
FROM a, b
WHERE ST_Area(ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom)) > 0.5 * ST_Area(a.geom)
      AND ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom) = true;
```

See this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41501/join-based-on-maximum-overlap-in-postgis-postgresql/41502#41502) if you are interested in finding the biggest areas instead of the one being greater than 50%

Comment: I think OP want delete `b.id` and  `0.5 * ST_Area(b.geom);` but the idea is good

Comment: May down-voters have the decency of explaining what they feel wrong with this answer?

Comment: This query  should work but it never seems to complete,  when I add a parameter such that it's only comparing the records in B to one record in A it successfully runs. I have a feeling this is a performance issue if table A has ~7000 records and table B has ~600 records?

Comment: Do you have spatial indexes on both geometry columns?

Comment: Add another condition. `AND ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom) = true` if you have index that will reduce the calculations of Intersections and area.

Comment: @JGH yes, after I add the condition it runs quickly. I just realized that the geometry is of type `MultiLineStringZM' for which ST_Area() is not a compatible function, the above query does not return anything.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza thank you for the comment, I have added it to the answer

Comment: Well intersection of lines is or one point, or multiple points. You wont get area for those neither. So what you want?